# clang-format works but git clang-format returns errors

Tags: git, clang-format

I have created a custom style file for `clang-format` and am able to run the following command to apply the stylistic coding changes:

`$ clang-format file_name.c --style=file`

I am now trying to use git clang-format so that the styling is only applied to modified code rather than the entire file. I staged my changes and ran the following command:

`$ git clang-format` or `$ git clang-format --style=file`

But I am getting the following error:

`error: cannot find executable "clang-format"`

Note that I installed clang-format by running the following command on my Windows machine:

`$ npm install -g clang-format`

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error? `clang-format` and `git-clang-format` are both installed in `C:\Users\profile\AppData\Roaming\npm`. I'm not sure why `clang-format` works but `git clang-format` doesn't.

I was expecting the stylistic changes to be applied to the staged changes, however that is not happening. I verified that the `git clang-format` command is recognized by bringing up the help menu via `git clang-format -h`. I added `C:\Users\profile\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my System Variables Path as well but that didn't change anything.

Comment: No `clang-format` (built-in) in git. Why do you think that's available? https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin.h

Comment: I know that git can be extended (with alias and other means) but then you need to put that _extension_ in one of very particular places.

Comment: git-clang-format can be called by git via `git clang-format`. I can run `git clang-format -h` and it works, so it does recognize the command.

Comment: Ok.... It is making a little more sense.... Then probably the extension is at the right place (and started) and then the _environment_ is not set correctly and why it can't find the executable (called from the extension) Add a line that prints `$PATH` when it starts. Might also help running git with `GIT_TRACE=1` to see what else it can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem but with Linux Debian13/"trixie". My solution may not direct help with Microsoft Windows but understanding the problem could help to fix it also on MS Win. It seems the [Git Integration script](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#git-integration) mixes up the path to `clang-format`. On calling it with `git clang-format-17` it asks for the installed script with the version and do not accept the generic name `clang-format` but that is used on scripts execution.

I just set an additional generic symbolic link `clang-format` to the original script. On my workstation it looks now like this:

```
~$ ls -l /usr/bin/clang-format*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 2024-01-13 00:28 /usr/bin/clang-format -> ../lib/llvm-17/bin/clang-format
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 2023-12-15 18:51 /usr/bin/clang-format-17 -> ../lib/llvm-17/bin/clang-format
```

Now git can find the script with `clang-format-17` and also with `clang-format`. I know MS Windows also support links. or copy the script with the missing name. I hope this can give an idea and help to solve your problem. The symptoms are very similar.